# Inverse limit of $l^{\infty}$ spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

I got stuck with one, presumably, easy problem:

Let $\varphi: l^{\infty} \rightarrow l^{\infty}$ be linear operator given by $\varphi(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}, \ldots, x_{n}, \ldots) = (x_{1}, \frac{x_{2}}{2}, \frac{x_{3}}{3}, \ldots, \frac{x_{n}}{n}, \ldots)$.

From the given data, let us constuct an inverse limit for the sequence:
$$
\newcommand{\la}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xleftarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{llllllllllll}
l^{\infty} & \la{\varphi} & l^{\infty} & \la{\varphi} & l^{\infty} & \la{\varphi} & l^{\infty} & \la{\varphi} & l^{\infty} & \la{\varphi} & \ldots
\end{array}
$$
Is it possible to understand, which space the inverse limit of this sequence is topologically isomorphic to?

Remark: here so-called "inverse limit" indicates that for the  given family $\{E_{\alpha} \}$ of topological vector spaces and the pair of indices $(\alpha, \beta)$ such that $\alpha \leq \beta$ there exists a continuous linear map $\psi_{\alpha \beta}: E_{\beta} \rightarrow E_{\alpha}$. So, the limit of such "inverse limit" is the subspace of a vector space $$\prod_{\alpha}{E_{\alpha}}$$ consisting of all elements $g \in \prod_{\alpha}{E_{\alpha}}$ such that $g(\alpha) = \psi_{\alpha \beta} g(\beta)$ for $\alpha \leq \beta$.

Comment: Inverse limit means the set of sequences fulfilling certain compatibility criterion. Can you define those sequences ?

Comment: @reuns Yes, you are right, but in the case above i was little confused by the terminology, apparently, the concerned notion is called "the limit of inverse spectrums of topological vector spaces", though i'm not sure that this name is generally accepted. I added some details to the post.

Comment: Why don't you make it concrete ? Your space is  $F = \{x = (x^0,x^1,x^2,\ldots ), x^k \in l^\infty,\varphi(x^{k+1}) = x^k\}$. From this it is quite clear $F  \cong \tilde{F} = \{y \in l^\infty, \forall k \ge 0, \sup_n |y(n) n^k| < \infty\}$, the isomorphism being $\tilde{F} \to F, y \mapsto (y, \varphi^{-1} y, \varphi^{-2} y, \ldots)$. What is your guess for the topology on $F$ and $\tilde{F}$ ?

Comment: @reuns Indeed, now, $\tilde{F}$ is precisely the space of "tempered sequences" that should be equipped with the topology, induced by the family of seminorms of such kind $p_{k}(y) = \sup_{n}{|y(n) n^{k}|}$, as you have just mentioned. What goes about $F$ -- the usual projective topology, the weakest topology that makes all the projection maps continuous?

Comment: Given you said $x^k \in l^\infty$ should we use the topology on $l^\infty$ as semi-norm ? Thus for $(a_m),b \in F$, $\lim_{m \to \infty} a_m = b$ iff $\forall k,\lim_{m \to \infty} \|a_m^k - b^k \|_\infty = 0$ ?  And the (natural) semi-norm you stated on $\tilde{F}$ is the weakest one making it complete ?